# Можно ли такое сверстать используя grid?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, grid

Возможно ли сделать такую вёрстку используя только grid и один общий контейнер для 7 новостей ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он абстрактный ("как сделать такую верстку"), и задан изображением (вместо текста описывающего конкретную проблему) - в таком виде, он не принесет пользы сообществу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

да возможно :

```
.element{

    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 130px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3,100px)///хз сколько у тебя там px подставиш сам

}
```

***PS не забуть про неявние гриди,grid-auto-rows, grid-auto-columns)***